# Build only on pull requests, and pass in branch name on Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, github, pytest

I have two builds set up in Jenkins: `buildA` and `buildB`. My developers will be committing and pushing code to `buildA`, and I'd like to trigger build jobs on Jenkins on `buildB` whenever a pull request on the `buildA` repo is issued.

My Jenkinsfile for `buildA` is quite simple:

```
build job: 'buildA', parameters: [gitParameter(name: 'BRANCH', value: env.BRANCH_NAME)]
```

This simply triggers `buildB` (Jenkinsfile snippet below):

```
sh label: "Install dependencies", script: 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
sh label: 'Execute tests', script: "pytest --custom-parameter ${BRANCH}"'
```

This works great so far. However, I've been noticing that my tests take quite a long time to run, and I'd like for the tests to only be triggered for pull requests. So far I've identified two options, and am wondering which one is the better practice:

**Option 1:** From what I understand, I can listen for only pull request events by setting this configuration below using a refspec:

[image].

**Option 2:** I've also heard that the you can use `env.CHANGE_ID` to check for pull request events. Therefore, my pipeline script would be altered to be

```
script {
    if (env.CHANGE_ID) {
         sh label: "Install dependencies", script: 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
        sh label: 'Execute tests', script: "pytest --custom-parameter ${BRANCH}"'
                    }
      }
```

**My question:** Which of these options is preferable for getting the branch name, and building only on pull requests from Git?

Comment: 2nd option is the way to go.... you have more control i.e. you can do certain tasks(Stages) based on the condition... in your case: run test cases only on PR and in push cases ignore them... which can be achieved using a simple if/else